# Can I check if a customer's card will be declined before charging with Stripe?

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment

I have the need to check if a user's account will be declined should a certain amount be deducted without actually deducting the amount. I could delete and create new customers each time I need to do this for the same user thus returning an error if they can't support any charges, or I can wait until I actually charge them but this will cause pretty big issues for me.

I was curious if its possible to run a check against the Stripe API to check if their card will be declined after they already have a customer associated with it. I've been using the test number:

```
  4000000000000341
```

But this still requires that I attempt to charge them.

Any ideas?

Comment: How does a declined transaction cause big issues for you? This is normal and common so your application shouldn't have any issues handling this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no way to tell if a card will be declined unless you process it. This is because the decline can only come from the payment processor who gets it from the card issuing bank. So only by running a transaction can you find out if a card will be declined.

The closest you can come to validating a card for a purchase without actually completing a transaction is to do an Authorization Only transaction. This allows you to run a  normal transaction in every way but you do not actually capture the funds. You "freeze" them and receive an authorization number which you use later to capture the transaction. But this still requires processing a transaction with the processor.

Comment: I've been looking everywhere for this answer, thanks! How exactly do you make a 'Authorization Only transaction'? Have you got any links? Thanks :)

Comment: @dspacejs https://stripe.com/docs/payments/capture-later; be sure to immediately void the charge so the person doesn't have a hold for a week or two on their card.